# Was versteht man unter dem Begriff "Hauptschrift"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich stehe mitte in Übersetzung eines Verhandlungsprotokolls. Fast am Ende steht ein Satz:
*Vorstehende Abschrift stimmt mit der in Urschrift vorliegenden Hauptschrift überein.*

Was sind also *Urschrift* und *Hauptschrift*? Ich dachte, *Urschrift* bedeutet *Original* oder *Urfassung*, aber was bedeutet hier *Hauptschrift*?

Answer (score 3):

Nach [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abschrift) und [VisumCentrale](https://visumcentrale.de/notarization-services) kann eine *Hauptschrift* eine *Urschrift* oder eine *Ausfertigung* oder eine *einfache oder beglaubigte Abschrift* sein.
Die *Urschrift* ist also immer das Original oder die Urfassung. Die zu bestätigende *Abschrift* muss aber nicht diese Urschrift als Vorlage haben, sondern kann selbst auf einer Abschrift beruhen.

Comment: Ja, sehe ich auch so, aber ich finde die Formulierung auch sehr "um die Ecke", man hätte den Begriff Hauptschrift einfach vermeiden können, dann wäre es klar gewesen. So wollte der Verfasser offenbar den Begriff Hauptschrift auch unbedingt verwenden und musste dabei darauf hinweisen, dass diese eben die Urschrift sein muss. Kein Beispiel klarer Sprache sicherlich.

Comment: @Philm: Die genannten Einschätzungen und Mutmaßungen kann ich nicht nachvollziehen. Juristische Texte sind in einer [Fachsprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fachsprache) geschrieben, für die zusätzliche oder andere Regeln gelten. Ich halte durchaus für möglich, wenn nicht sogar für wahrscheinlich, dass das eine Standardformulierung ist, die den Sachverhalt juristisch eindeutig wiedergibt.

Comment: Erstens: Mit der Fachsprache hast Du recht, und man muss meiner Einschätzung dieser Formulierung auch nicht folgen, aber das ändert nichts am wenig bestreitbaren von mir erwähnten Fakt, dass die Konstruktion nur nötig ist, wenn man den Begriff *Hauptschrift* (aus welchen Gründen auch immer) erwähnen will oder muss.

Comment: Zweitens: Ich erhalte meine einleitende Einschätzung aber (begründet) nicht zuletzt deswegen aufrecht, weil eine schnelle Recherche in diversen einschlägigen Gesetzestexten zu Abschriften und Urkunden den Begriff *Urschrift* klar benennen, z.B. https://dejure.org/gesetze/BeurkG/42.html (aber man findet dutzende Andere), während "Hauptschrift" kein juristisch zumindest in Gesetzestexten adäquat relevanter Begriff zu sein schein, konkret in einer ad hoc Internet-Suche über deutsche Gesetzestexte schlicht nicht vorkommt.

Comment: Nochmal: Dies ist im Unterschied zum Vorgenannten ("Erstens") eine Einschätzung, die ich mit "Ich finde" eingeleitet habe und hiermit nochmal unterfüttere. Ich stelle etwas begründet in Frage, das heißt nicht, dass ich mir anmaße, zu 100% über die fachlichen/fachsprachlichen Gründe, den Begriff "Hauptschrift" einzuflechten, abschließend zu urteilen. – Ich hoffe, Du kannst es jetzt zumindest "nachvollziehen", was ja nicht zustimmen heißt.

Comment: Ist sicher auch eine Frage persönlichen Geschmacks, ich halte Kritik auch an vermeintlichen Autoritäten, solange sie begründet wird, für nicht unzulässig- niemand dürfte etwa sonst eine Regierung kritisieren, weil ja niemand 100% Einblick in die Entscheidungsgrundlagen hat. Und ganz besonders in Deutschland ist der Glaube an Obrigkeiten nach meinem Geschmack zu sehr ausgeprägt, wie die Historie auch aufzeigt.